# jQuery - Image management

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery

Is there a jQuery plug-in / JavaScript control that will allow me to display array of images, but with (at least) option to delete image on certain user action.

Something like this: http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/index.php but with dedicated delete button on every image.

First extra option that I can think of is to rearrange order of images.

If not... I guess I'll start extending mentioned jcarousellite myself....

Comment: There are some filemanager for asp.net - but if you search for carousel with menou, probably you need to add the menu by your self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a click event to each image and some jQuery to remove the image from the list. There is no need to write a separate plugin. Syntax below might be wrong. I am writing this on my phone so no way to check. But you get the picture (sic).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("div.jCarouselLite > img").click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>

        <div class="jCarouselLite">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="image/1.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="118"></li>

                <li><img src="image/2.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="118"></li>
                <li><img src="image/3.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="118"></li>
                <li><img src="image/4.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="118"></li>
                <li><img src="image/5.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="118"></li>
                <li><img src="image/6.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="118"></li>
                <li><img src="image/7.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="118"></li>
                <li><img src="image/8.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="118"></li>
                <li><img src="image/9.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="118"></li>
                <li><img src="image/10.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="118"></li>

                <li><img src="image/11.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="118"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: I am assuming that you just want the user to be able to temporarily delete the image from the page. Or do you want the delete to remove it from the page every time the page is rendered thereafter? This would need some server-side code as well.

Comment: Thanks for jQuery code - I'm still learning it, so it's nice to see how to user selector. As for server side deleting - it won't be a problem, I'm proficient with ASP.NET.

I'll wait a little bit to see if anyone has link to another plug-in that already has this functionality... if not I'll probably use code you gave me (+add alerts for delete and server-side calls).

Thanks again.

Comment: If you do need to make calls back to the server, use the jQuery AJAX functionality.